# Fortran nested do loops to calculate tensor product

Tags: matrix, fortran, linear-algebra

As an exercise, I'm trying to calculate a [tensor product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerProduct.html) using `do` loops in Fortran. I use the same notation in [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerProduct.html) in my code to evaluate the tensor product of matrices `A` and `B`:

```
program test

implicit none
real, dimension (3,3) :: A
real, dimension (4,2) :: B
real, dimension (:,:), allocatable :: C
integer :: i, j, k, l, m, n, p, q, alpha, beta
integer :: Ccols, Crows

A = reshape( (/ 1, 0, 2, 1, 9, 5, 1, 4, -1 /), shape(A) )
B = reshape( (/ 1, -2, 9, 5, 4, -1, 3, 9 /), shape( B ) )

m = size(A,1) ! no. A rows
n = size(A,2) ! no. A cols
p = size(B,1) ! no. B rows
q = size(B,2) ! no. B cols
allocate(C(m*p, n*q)) ! m*p columns, n*q rows
C = 0

do i = 1, n  ! iterate over A cols
    do j = 1, m  ! iterate over A rows
        do k = 1, q  ! iterate over B cols
            do l = 1, p  ! iterate over B rows
                alpha = p*(i-1) + k  ! C row index
                beta = q*(j-1) + l  ! C col index
                C(beta, alpha) = A(i,j) * B(k,l)
            end do
        end do
    end do
end do

print *, C

end program test
```

The resulting matrix `C` does not agree with the result generated using Python's [numpy.kron](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) function which gives a 12x6 matrix

```
>> import numpy as np
>> A = np.array([[1,0,2],[1,9,5],[1,4,-1]])
>> B = np.array([[1,-2],[9,5],[4,-1],[3,9]])
>> np.kron(A,B)

   [[  1,  -2,   0,   0,   2,  -4],
    [  9,   5,   0,   0,  18,  10],
    [  4,  -1,   0,   0,   8,  -2],
    [  3,   9,   0,   0,   6,  18],
    [  1,  -2,   9, -18,   5, -10],
    [  9,   5,  81,  45,  45,  25],
    [  4,  -1,  36,  -9,  20,  -5],
    [  3,   9,  27,  81,  15,  45],
    [  1,  -2,   4,  -8,  -1,   2],
    [  9,   5,  36,  20,  -9,  -5],
    [  4,  -1,  16,  -4,  -4,   1],
    [  3,   9,  12,  36,  -3,  -9]]
```

What am I doing wrong in the Fortran code?

Comment: I think you need to switch the p and q in your definitions of alpha and beta.

Comment: thanks @joe but I still get the wrong answer

Comment: You are messing some indexes between rows and columns. If `i` iterates overs columns and `j` over rows, then you should address `A(j,i)` and not `A(i,j)`. Moreover the initializations of `A` and `B` is probably not what you think: for instance here `[1,0,2]` will be the first column of `A`, not the first row. And last, `print*, C` won't print the matrix by rows.

Comment: I'm not sure if my comment is the only problem, but it definitely is a problem; since `i = 1, n` and `k = 1, q`, it should be `q*(i-1) + k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PierU has already pointed out, matrices A and B aren't actually initialised in the way that you think. Fortran uses column-major order, whilst Python's numpy arrays use row-major order. You would need to fix those before even considering the rest. I often use `transpose()` here.

I (personally) think debugging would be easier with variables clearly named in terms of what they stand for (row and columns) rather than m, n, p, q. Also, `l` is an awkward variable name, because it can be misread as 1, I in different fonts or by ageing programmers without their reading glasses on. But I've left it for now!

```
program test
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: Arows = 3, Acols = 3
   integer, parameter :: Brows = 4, Bcols = 2
   real, allocatable :: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)
   integer i, j, k, l, alpha, beta
   character(len=*), parameter :: fmt = "f6.1"

   A = transpose(   reshape( [ 1, 0, 2, 1, 9, 5, 1, 4, -1 ], [ Acols, Arows ] )   )
   B = transpose(   reshape( [ 1, -2, 9, 5, 4, -1, 3, 9 ]  , [ Bcols, Brows ] )   )
   allocate( C(Arows*Brows,Acols*Bcols) )

   do i = 1, Arows
      do j = 1, Acols
         do k = 1, Brows
            do l = 1, Bcols
               alpha = Brows * ( i - 1 ) + k
               beta  = Bcols * ( j - 1 ) + l
               C(alpha,beta) = A(i,j) * B(k,l)
            end do
         end do
      end do
   end do

   call printMatrix( "A:", A, fmt )
   call printMatrix( "B:", B, fmt )
   call printMatrix( "C:", C, fmt )

contains

   subroutine printMatrix( title, M, fm )
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: title
      real, intent(in) :: M(:,:)
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: fm
      integer row

      write( *, * ) title
      do row = 1, size( M, 1 )
         write( *, "( *( 1x, " // fm // " ) )"  ) M(row,:)
      end do
      write( *, * )

   end subroutine printMatrix

end program test
```

Output:

```
 A:
     1.0     0.0     2.0
     1.0     9.0     5.0
     1.0     4.0    -1.0

 B:
     1.0    -2.0
     9.0     5.0
     4.0    -1.0
     3.0     9.0

 C:
     1.0    -2.0     0.0    -0.0     2.0    -4.0
     9.0     5.0     0.0     0.0    18.0    10.0
     4.0    -1.0     0.0    -0.0     8.0    -2.0
     3.0     9.0     0.0     0.0     6.0    18.0
     1.0    -2.0     9.0   -18.0     5.0   -10.0
     9.0     5.0    81.0    45.0    45.0    25.0
     4.0    -1.0    36.0    -9.0    20.0    -5.0
     3.0     9.0    27.0    81.0    15.0    45.0
     1.0    -2.0     4.0    -8.0    -1.0     2.0
     9.0     5.0    36.0    20.0    -9.0    -5.0
     4.0    -1.0    16.0    -4.0    -4.0     1.0
     3.0     9.0    12.0    36.0    -3.0    -9.0
```

For reference, the (non-interactive) Python version is

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array( [ [1,0,2], [1,9,5] , [1,4,-1] ] )
B = np.array( [ [1,-2], [9,5] , [4,-1], [3,9] ] )
print( np.kron( A, B ) )
```

with output

```
[[  1  -2   0   0   2  -4]
 [  9   5   0   0  18  10]
 [  4  -1   0   0   8  -2]
 [  3   9   0   0   6  18]
 [  1  -2   9 -18   5 -10]
 [  9   5  81  45  45  25]
 [  4  -1  36  -9  20  -5]
 [  3   9  27  81  15  45]
 [  1  -2   4  -8  -1   2]
 [  9   5  36  20  -9  -5]
 [  4  -1  16  -4  -4   1]
 [  3   9  12  36  -3  -9]]
```